# Retrieving the count distribution of groups of cells in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have a .csv open in Excel 2007 that looks like the following

```
1 566
1 566
1 566
2 341
2 341
3 566
3 566
3 566
3 566
...
```

There is a one-to-one relationship between Column A and B, but B is not unique (but can only take a small set of valid values). I wish to query how many id's (Column A) contain a particular property (Column B). If the example above ended before the "...", I would like to get as the output:

```
566 2
341 1
```

because the property 566 is owned by two id's (1 and 3) and the property 341 is only owned by the id 2.

I think this would be much easier on a relational database, but I have to use Excel.

Comment: If you are able to modify the original data set you can use remove duplicates to get rid of the repeating entries then use countif to count the uniques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is in A2:B100 then try this "array formula" in E2

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(B$2:B$100=D2,IF(A$2:A$100<>"",MATCH(A$2:A$100,A$2:A$100,0))),ROW(B$2:B$100)-ROW(B$2)+1),1))`

confirmed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

where D2 contains a specific property like 566